# How can I block ping requests with IPTables?

Tags: 10.10, security, firewall, iptables

and stealth specific ports?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To deny responses to ping requests..Add the following iptable rule

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -o eth0 -j ACCEPT          
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT     
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT       
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -i eth0 -j DROP
```

Comment: something is wrong with the rules or i just don't have dependencies, i changed the eth0 to wlan0 as i am on my laptop right now, and received the error "sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp –icmp-type destination-unreachable -s 0/0 -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
Bad argument `–icmp-type'" and "sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -i wlan0-j DROP
Bad argument `DROP'"

Comment: @david25 see my updated answer.

Answer (score 9):

I believe `iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP` should do the trick.

For IPv6 you would need something like `ip6tables -I INPUT -p icmpv6 --icmp-type 8 -j DROP`.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest method of disabling ping response is to add an entry in /etc/sysctl.conf file. If the Iptables flushes or stop server will start responding to ping responses again. I suggest the following entry in your /etc/sysctl.conf file

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
```

this will tell kernel to not respond any ping response, after this run sysctl -p on shell to implement the changes without reboot.

For more info please refer: http://www.trickylinux.net/disable-ping-response-linux/

Comment: This is probably the best way I have found in the past. It has the plus side that its persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Drop ICMP echo requests ("Ping"):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

What do you mean by stealth? You could just DROP all incoming packets. Google provided this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m stealth -j REJECT
```

But on (my) Ubuntu box, iptables does not know of a "stealth" match. As it seems, you can do lots of interesting stuff with xtables:

```
aptitude show xtables-addons-common
```